# Analysis services with PowerBI

Tags: service, powerbi, analysis

I got authentication problems while connecting PowerBI to Analysis services on premise  . 
I read that we need to do User Principal Name (UPN) mapping but i do not have a domain , Analysis services is on an azure virtual machine  . 
So my question is , if i do configure HTTP Access to Analysis services would that be a solution that works with PowerBI  ?  Is it possible for PowerBI to connect to the Analysis services  HTTP end point ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of now it's not possible to connect to SSAS hosted on a server outside of your AD domain from Power BI Service (with scheduled refresh functionality). It doesn't work in import nor DirectQuery mode.

#### Power BI Desktop

From Power BI Desktop (when authoring a report) it's possible to use import mode with HTTP(S) access to SSAS through MSMDPUMP interface with Basic authentication.

It's even possible to use DirectQuery mode with direct (not HTTP) connection to SSAS, when the name and password of your account on SSAS and account you are logged in on computer running Power BI Desktop are the same. Or you can use Windows Credential Manager to set the credentials for SSAS host.

#### Power BI Service

None of those ways work when you publish your report to Power BI Service. You cannot refresh your dataset directly and you cannot refresh it through On-premise Data Gateway.

#### Possible solutions

1. Use Active Directory

You can create separate AD environment for your SSAS server. It doesn't have to be the same AD domain that is synced with Azure AD tenant that you use for logging into Power BI Service. It just has to be AD. Then you can install On-premise Data Gateway directly on this SSAS server and add it to your Power BI Service environment. Then you have to add SSAS connection for this gateway and map Power BI users to SSAS AD users. Then the scheduled refresh functionality should work through this On-premise Data Gateway in import mode. I'm not entirely sure about DirectQuery.

2. Query proxy (only for MDX queries)

If your usage scenario needs only some data from your SSAS instance, maybe it will be possible to get the data by using MDX queries. If that's the case, then you can deploy and use **my simple SSAS query proxy** application written in ASP.NET.

https://github.com/jmarsik/SSASQueryProxy

I'm an author of this application, but it shouldn't be a problem, it's open source and it partially helps in this situation. I have used it for a few mostly simple dashboards for customers that wanted Power BI Service functionality (mainly access from mobile devices and automated refresh) for subset of the data they had in their hosted SSAS instances (outside of their AD domains).

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are missing here is the On Premise Gateway. You need to install one in order to manage you live conection to on premise.

Here is some explination.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-enterprise-manage-ssas

The mapping is only for cases that your domain doesn't match with you azure AD domain. Example, you login in azure with @company.com but your email and institution stuff are with @companyfullname.org
When this domain are different you should add rules to match.

Regards

Comment: The problem here is that i do not have a domain at all , the analysis service is on a machine on azure . Things work very well with the gateway when  i am using SQL server , but when using Analysis services it does not work cause of authentication .    Any way i can make it work without being part of a domain ?

Comment: Which accout are you using to connect to SSAS? when you start sql manamenet and connect to ssas, that account should be mapped with the azure ad you use for power bi service.

Comment: I am using a local windows account to connect to Analysis services .  I do not know how to map that ?