# Unable to access SSAS Tabular instance remotely/from Power BI Service Using HTTP Endpoints

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, analysisservices

I configured HTTP Endpoints for Analysis services tabular instance (SQL Server 2017) on IIS 10 in Windows server 2019 and I am able to connect this tabular instance on local machine by using HTTP endpoints. I  also created some Power BI reports and it is also working fine with HTTP endpoints in Power BI Desktop.

But when I deployed these reports on Power BI service and try to run then it shows following error message:

"The connection to Analysis Service instance timed out or was lost. Ensure that the server and 'SQL Browser' Service are running."

I tried to access HTTP endpoints after disabling Firewall also, but getting same error on Power BI service and in remote access.

The machine on which SSAS tabular instance installed is not in domain, and I am trying to connect it from other domain remotely/using Power Bi Service.

Please refer following link:

[Analysis services with PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978620/analysis-services-with-powerbi)

Is this the root cause of issue?

Note: SQL Server Browser service is also running on Machine.

Please let me know if I missed something.

Thanks in Advance.

Hemant

Comment: You're trying to connect from the internet (Power BI Service) to your local server. In a corporate environment there are any number of firewalls in the way (not just the one on your computer). The usual solution is to install a PowerBI gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick. Power BI Gateway is already installed and we are able to connect other sources like SQL server using Power BI Gateway and Dashboard reports are running fine using the same. Only SSAS tabular source is not working in our case.

Comment: Can you go the server with your Power BI gateway and try the "Network Port Test" as per here and confirm that the gateway can connect to the HTTP endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-tshoot#collect-logs-from-the-on-premises-data-gateway-app. Also can you edit your   question and add the information that you have a gateway installed and that it works for everything except http endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

AS per Anand in following link:

[Analysis services with PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978620/analysis-services-with-powerbi)

Possible solutions are:

1) Use Active Directory

You can create separate AD environment for your SSAS server. It doesn't have to be the same AD domain that is synced with Azure AD tenant that you use for logging into Power BI Service. It just has to be AD. Then you can install On-premise Data Gateway directly on this SSAS server and add it to your Power BI Service environment. Then you have to add SSAS connection for this gateway and map Power BI users to SSAS AD users. Then the scheduled refresh functionality should work through this On-premise Data Gateway in import mode. I'm not entirely sure about DirectQuery.

2) Query proxy (only for MDX queries)

If your usage scenario needs only some data from your SSAS instance, maybe it will be possible to get the data by using MDX queries. If that's the case, then you can deploy and use my simple SSAS query proxy application written in ASP.NET.

So do I need to use Active Directory for the same? Please confirm.

Hemant